# Can the ActionView form input methods create <input> tags with inner html?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, actionview

I am generating an input like this:

```
<%= form.radio_button("ans", ans.num.to_s) %>
```

The generated html is:

```
<input id="myform_ans_1" name="myform[ans]" type="radio" value="1" />
```

But what I am looking for is this html:

```
<input id="myform_ans_1" name="myform[ans]" type="radio" value="1">Some Text</input>
```

Is there an option that I can pass into the radio_button method render the desired html?

As I understand the optional `options hash` that you can pass to `radio_button`, this only adds attributes to the html tag.

Comment: Is that valid markup?  I don't even know what that renders...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app will involve a lot of forms you should definitely take a look at [formtastic](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic).  You can define your forms like so:

```
<% semantic_form_for @article do |form| %>

  <% form.inputs :name => "New Article" do %>
    <%= form.input :title %>
    <%= form.input :body %>
  <% end %>

  <% form.buttons do %>
    <%= form.commit_button %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

This will generate all the markup required for html forms including fieldsets, legends, inputs and labels.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `<label>` tags with `for` attribute like this:

```
<input id="myform_ans_1" ... /><label for="myform_ans_1">Foobar</label>
```

And no, there is no parameter for that. You'll just have to use the label helper.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p><%= form.radio_button("ans", ans.num.to_s) %>

<%= form.label("Some Text") %></p>
```

Comment: This works, but I added `<%= form.label(:"ans_#{ans.num}", "Some Text") %>` to make the for attribute of the label be the same as the id for the input field.